# Invalid server-key when performing a POST request to FCM?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user) for push notifications, and I'm stuck at the part where it says

> To trigger a push message, make a POST request to this URL.

I generated the public and private keys using [this site](https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/) and placed the public key in the `applicationServerKey` key before calling `registration.pushManager.subscribe`, and I get a properly formatted JSON response, but I'm unsure of how exactly to generate the `Authorization` header for use in the POST request to send a notification. Here's what the JSON response from `subscribe` looks like:

```
{
  "endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/asdf:qwer",
  "expirationTime":null,
  "keys":{"p256dh":"key","auth":"auth"}
}
```

I surmised that the portion after `/send` should be placed in the `to` field, but I'm unsure of how to format the `Authorization` header. Surely I should need to use the private key in some way, but I'm not sure how.

My assumption is that I need to perform some sort of operation on my private key, the `p256dh` field, and the `auth` field, and that result will be placed in the `key=` field in the POST request, but I cannot find the reference for this.

Do you *need* to create a Firebase project to do this? I'm unsure of whether or not this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all access to Firebase products and services requires the creation of a Firebase project.  You can't use arbitrary keys to invoke FCM.  You must use a service account that's been granted permission to call the API.

Comment: Then what is the point of [this site](https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/) mentioned in the Google tutorial? Why generate keys if you cannot use them?

Comment: I don't know.  Try following the FCM documentation.

Comment: That's what I was doing? Isn't Firebase owned by Google? [That step](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user) is officially mentioned in their tutorial for setting up push notifications. "You can create a public and private set of application server keys by visiting ..."

Comment: Also, isn't the whole idea behind VAPID is such that you don't need to create a Firebase project? So you should be able to use generated private/public keys?

Comment: The formal FCM documentation can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: I have a suspicion that this answer is inaccurate. "VAPID authentication prevents unknown sources sending notifications to the client and allows sending notifications to Chrome without signing in to Firebase and providing a GCM API key."

Comment: The formal documentation should clear up any concerns that you have. But you will need to create a Firebase project that identifies your web clients: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#add_firebase_to_your_javascript_project

Comment: I really don't know who to trust here. Numerous sources say creating a Firebase project is unnecessary, and you don't seem to be rebutting them, opting instead to link to generic documentation.

Comment: That is the formal documentation supported by the Firebase team.  You can take it or leave it, or even contact Firebase support directly with your concerns.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I'm aware that documentation exists. I'm asking specifically whether or not you need to create a Firebase project to POST a notification. You state that this is the case, but I think you may be lying? Other sources seem to indicate that you can use VAPID keys to bypass this.

Comment: I'm not trying to deceive you.  I'm stating the facts from my experience sending messages through FCM.  You can take it or leave it.

Comment: This is a very strange exchange. I don't really know what to make of it. I suppose I need to do more research since you work with Firebase and this may be influencing your answers in some way.

Comment: I no longer work for Google.  I am speaking from personal experience.

Comment: The reason I suspect deceit is because you are clearly extremely knowledgeable of Firebase, having worked there, and yet seem to dodge my mentions of using VAPID keys. You state in your answer that you need to register your project with Firebase, but numerous other sources indicate that this is not the case, and that VAPID keys alleviate this.

Comment: I don't know anything about VAPID.  All of the messages I've sent through FCM involve a Firebase project.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer then if you don't know anything about VAPID, as your answer is currently very authoritative, which may be misleading to others, as it may not be accurate.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help.